# Can one find liberation independent for himself?

Tags: nirvana, buddha

Ven. Members of the Sangha, Ven. Fellows,
Valued Upasaka, Upasika,
Dear readers and interested,

[- Namo tassa bhagavato arahato sammā-sambuddhassa -](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/homage_en.html)

since the root-consideration of this possible vey popular idee "you can", is very deep connected with the fundation for the path liberation, right view, in means of gratitude, e.g. "there is mother and father, gifts and sacrifies...", my person thought that it's maybe interesting to investigate this matter of the abcestor-ship of the Noble One more in detail, so to possible cut of "when ever I like, I could" yet with it's rare oppotunities, that one really could.

Can a being develope *indepentently* the path, it's skills, requirements... to awakening for itself?

Or does it nevertheless have "mother and father, gifts and sacrifies... brahmans or contemplatives who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, (proclaim this world & the next after having directly known & realized it for themselves)*" as prerequisite?

*. *set in brackes, given here that nobody would proclaim, as foundation for this idea*

References and similies of and from the past Noble Ones, Buddhas, Paccecabuddhas, there history... welcome.
(Stories like Devatatta, who is said to become a Paccecabuddha one time, come to mind, yet met and taught by a Buddha...)

(*Note: This question is not meant for use of commercial purpose or any other wordily gain, but intended for liberation only, so to give and share without bound to the world*)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but it is something like trying to re-invent the wheel or discover electricity.

Comment: Good argument to prevent from doing, but does not cut of the believe that having access to knowledge about electricity is lasting and therefore does not answer the question, meets it's purpose and seems to be based exclusively on assuming, believe without even reasoning, Nyom Sarath. It's not a question for someone satisfied in firm confidence at least, mere a challenge on saddha. Tell, how could Sarath!

Comment: @Bhante. This is not a discussion-site. Please use the Chat-rooms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But  we don't wanna act like a chimpanzee  which try to make own evolution to be a human. In the other word, we don't have millions years old to change ourselves from a chimpanzee to a human.

Comment: Acariya Warapol says "yes". Then please explain. To understand why, see comment under Upasaka Saraths similar answer, since this does not answer the question and it's purpose.

Comment: Buddha wandered in Samsara for many aeons practicing to be a Buddha. We have to do the same if we want to be a Buddha ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The enlightened mind is independent (MN 56; MN 38) & *viveka*. Even though the Buddha has gifted the path, in the state of liberation there is independence from the teacher (MN 56).

"*There is mother and father, gifts & sacrifices*" is bondage (*upadhi*) & not liberation (MN 117).

"*There is mother and father, gifts & sacrifices*" is meritorious right view for *puthujjana* (worldlings).

Answer (score -1):

No.

One must sacrifice and give immense treasures in order to advance on his path towards liberation.

One, who has sacrificed and given immense treasures, will be born in such a future where liberation is just a mere steps ahead.

The merit he has done, will define if he will be able to attain liberation independently or not.

There are beings which acquired such a high degree of merit by sacrificing and giving gifts, that they are born by apparition, in healthy and long lasting bodies, sitting in lotus stance, meditating and contemplating the truth independently for themselves. But even these, as you see, had to sacrifice and give, in order to be rewarded with such and such future.